Broken custom GRUB Entry, boots into drive, but doesn't mount everything properly
I dual boot my computer with LibreELEC, but I can only access it with the motherboard's boot menu, so I wanted to add it to my GRUB so I don't spam F12 everytime I want to boot into it.
For some reason os-prober and update-grub did not detect and create a new entry, so I have tried creating a GRUB entry to boot directly into it:
My output for lsblk --fs is:
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│    vfat   FAT16 System
│                       11B7-1563                                           
└─sda2
     ext4   1.0   Storage
                        23030aa8-e18a-4c1c-a469-9adf42f00303                
nvme0n1
                                                                            
├─nvme0n1p1
│    vfat   FAT32       A91C-A1E0                             505,2M     1% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2
│    ext4   1.0         f215bc54-2802-478a-aff9-5e1a68b002bd   13,3G    46% /
├─nvme0n1p3
│    swap   1           b1245cc7-b47c-44b2-b2de-1c7609a9e799                [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p4
     ext4   1.0         5aad4210-4033-4cdd-a4c8-ad4730253af2  513,1G    37% /home


My Debian install is in the NVME drive and LibreELEC is in the SSD (sda). My custom boot entry looks as follows:
set root='(hd1,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11B7-1563
linux /KERNEL boot=UUID=11B7-1563 disk=UUID=11B7-1563 storage=UUID=23030aa8-e18a-4c1c-a469-9adf42f00303
initrd /SYSTEM
boot


When choosing it in the bootloader, it get's into the system and in the splash screen I get an error where it says it could not mount UUID=11B7-1563 and says something about mounting the storage. I'm not quite sure what's wrong with my boot entry, when booting from the motherboard's bootloader it works just fine.
